# Why is the singularity not taken into account?

Tags: mathematical-physics, potential, singularities, magnetic-moment, dipole

In this article "[Reflections on Maxwell’s Treatise](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b395/1ef16ff023237fa3516627c5264fc9fd57bc.pdf)", Section 4.2, it says:

He replaces $\mathbf{m}$ with a volume element of magnetization $\mathbf{M}\ dV$ , integrates over $V$ , and lets the same integral define the magnetic potential inside as well as outside the magnetization to get in Art. $385$ equation $8$ ([of Maxwell's treatise](https://archive.org/details/ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetism-Volume2/page/n33)):

$\displaystyle \psi_m (\mathbf {r})=\dfrac{1}{4 \pi} \int_{V'} \mathbf{M(r')}.\nabla'  \left(     \dfrac{1}{\left|   \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}  \right|}       \right) dV' \tag{22}$

Why is the singularity in equation $(22)$ not taken into account?

Shouldn't we use the following improper integral instead of equation $(22)$:

$$\displaystyle \psi_m (\mathbf {r})=\dfrac{1}{4 \pi} \lim \limits_{\delta V' \to 0} \int_{V'-\delta V'} \mathbf{M(r')}.\nabla'  \left(     \dfrac{1}{\left|   \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}  \right|}       \right) dV' $$

How shall we show this integral converges (without using the spherical volume element) using Cartesian coordiante system?

Comment: What do you mean by ignored? If it doesn't make the [improper integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) divergent, there's nothing to ignore.

Comment: Have you checked if it really is a singularity if you take into account the suppressing factor in the volume element?

Comment: @Qmechanic: I think using spherical element, it would be removable singularity???

Comment: @Ruslan: How can we show the improper integral $\displaystyle \psi_m (\mathbf {r})=\dfrac{1}{4 \pi} \lim \limits_{\delta V' \to 0} \int_{V'-\delta V'} \mathbf{M(r')}.\nabla'  \left(     \dfrac{1}{\left|   \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}  \right|}       \right) dV'$  converges?

Comment: Also posted (under a different user id?) at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3135817/